# Por que sequelize me cambia la hora

Tags: javascript, mysql, nodejs, sequelize.js

Hola estoy tratando de hacer una consulta entre fechas con Sequelize pero el loggin de la consulta muestra una fecha diferente a la que se envia.

Consulta:

```js
async function findBetweenDates(startDate, endDate) {
    let starDate = '2022-09-01';
    let endDate = '2022-09-12';
    startDate = new Date(startDate); // 2022-09-01T00:00:00.000Z
    endDate = new Date(endDate); // 2022-10-13T00:00:00.000Z 
    const notes = await models.Note.findAll( {
        where: {
            date: { [Op.between]: [startDate, endDate] }
        }
    })
    if (notes == null) return false;
    return notes;
}

// resulta Executing (default): SELECT `note_id`, `credit_id`, `debit_id`, `date`, `credit`, `debit`, `active`, `createdAt` FROM `notes` AS `Note` WHERE `Note`.`date` BETWEEN '2022-08-31 19:00:00' AND '2022-10-12 19:00:00';
```

Sequelize:

```js
const URI = `mysql://${USER}:${PASSWORD}@${config.dbHost}:${config.dbPort}/${config.dbName}`;

const options = {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    logging: true,
    timezone: '-05:00',
    define: {
        timestamps: false
    }
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(URI, options);
```

Comment: es correcto `2022-10-13T00:00:00.000Z` -5 horas del timezone da `2022-10-12 19:00:00` o no le pones timezone o le envias el date con el timezone correcto, actualmente se la envias con la [Z de Zulu o timezone UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC))

Comment: Igual es una tontería, pero la variable `let starDate = '2022-09-01';`no es la misma en `startDate = new Date(startDate);`, a la primera le faltaría una letra t.